# Is it possible to use a custom picture as the bars in a bar chart?

Tags: r, excel, data-visualization, tableau-api, business-intelligence

I have data that I'd like to plot, and instead of regular vertical bars showing the value of the y-axis, I'd like to either:

1) fill up the bar with a picture (a Christmas ornament pattern, for example)

2) use a custom picture (such as a candle, let's say) as the bar

is this possible? My preferred platform is either R, Excel, or Tableau public.

Comment: In R, this would be difficult and require hacks or workarounds. That's by design. Cute pictures rarely add additional information or clarity to a figure, so authors of graphics packages typically don't include funtions to add pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```r
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(lattice)

#download Chrismas tree image which will be used as bar in barplot
download.file("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Poinsettia_tree.jpg", "Poinsettia_tree.jpg")
chrismas_tree <- readJPEG("Poinsettia_tree.jpg")

#sample data for barplot
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)

#barplot
barchart(counts, origin=0, col="white",horizontal = FALSE,
             panel=function(x, y, ...) {
             panel.barchart(x, y, ...)
             grid.raster(chrismas_tree, y=0, height=y, x=x,
                               default.units="native", 
                               just="bottom",
                               width=unit(0.2,"npc"))
             },
         ylab = "Counts",
         xlab = "Gear",
         main = "Gear counts plot (mtcars)")
```

[image: Output plot]

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: @Siva - it's in `R`

Comment: @Prem great how can we embeed R in tableau? can you provide some insight?

Comment: @Siva hopefully [this](https://community.tableau.com/thread/236068) will get you started.

Answer (score 2):

In excel 2013 you can fill the columns in a chart with an image file. Select the column by right clicking on it and then select format data point from the pop-up menu. Select the paint bucket tab, under the fill option choose picture or texture fill, then insert picture from file. The image is now overlaid on the column for the chart.